# Get request doesn't work inside a Form with post method

Tags: html, forms, laravel, laravel-4

The site gives a **No Data Received** error if the href in the anchor for the *delete button* is `{{ URL::to('admin/delete', array($url->id)) }}` which is a get request, if removed, it works fine but of course the *delete button* does nothing.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

In **View.blade.php**:

```
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/update', 'method' => 'post', 'files'=>true)) }}
    <table>
         <tr>
              <td colspan="5" align="right">
                   <a id="$url->id" href="{{ URL::to('admin/delete', array($url->id)) }}"
                            onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete?');">
                        <button class="delete"name="new" type="button">delete</button>
                   </a>
              </td>
         </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <input class="button_green button_submit" type="submit" value="update" />
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

in **routes.php**

```
Route::post('/admin/update', 'UrlController@postUpdateUrl');
Route::get('/admin/delete/{id}', 'UrlController@getDeleteUrl');
```

Comment: When do you have the `No Data Received` error ? When you load the page with the button or when you click on the button ?

Comment: please check if `$url->id` has a value ;)

Comment: Can you post your full routes.php file please, so we can see how your controllers are setup, also the whole UrlController.php file would be useful.

Comment: should it not be array('id'=>$url->id)?

Comment: please post your ``getDeleteUrl`` function here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test, try using this on your href line to:

```
<a id="1" href="{{ URL::to('admin/delete', array(1)) }}"
                        onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete?');">
```

It's just to make sure your view will render as it should.

If it works you can get your previous code back, because your problem is in the controller that renders this particular view. You should have **something like** this there for it to work:

```
class UrlController extends Controller {

    public function getDeleteUrl($id)
    {
        $url = URL::find($id);

        return View::make('View')->with('url', $url);
    }

}
```

Look, as you didn't posted your controller, I'm assuming you have a model called URL, if you don't, you should edit the code to support your model names. I'm also assuming that your view file name is View, change it, if it's wrong.